Suppression of low network traffic in the switch?
I recently had a situation with my photovoltaic system where the inverter and controller didn't want to talk to each other. As a result, the manufacturer's monitoring app did not show me any current production and consumption values. The electrical company explained this to me: In rare cases, it can happen that the intermediate switch (in my case, just a network of home routers and repeaters) prevents communication between two devices if they only exchange a few messages with each other. This feature would be called "Data Snooping".
I know a little about networks and IT security, even if not in depth. As it turned out, the reason for the lack of communication was not this exotic feature, but the devices were located in different subnets (home LAN, guest network), which are not allowed to talk to each other for good reason. After I moved both devices to the guest network, they talk to each other again. So far, so good.
But I'm still a bit confused. To my knowledge, Data Snooping means unauthorized, silent listening to data without manipulation. I can certainly imagine a use case in an attack scenario that would make the aforementioned feature useful. However, I can't find anything about it in the home router interface. In an internet search, the most I can find is IGMP snooping, DHCP snooping and traffic shaping. None of them really fit, at best traffic shaping goes in this direction.
Have you ever come across this feature, and if so, in which direction should I think further?

If the router segregates both networks, why would you expect to communicate across it?

It was not me, but the electrician, who expected the devices to communicate over the segregated networks. I guess, he lacked sufficient network skills, as this is basic network stuff.

The solutions for all my network problems were:

Connect both devices, each per cable, to the same switch.
Put them both into the same subnet.

“It could be that the person you've talked to has seen this happen once and made up their own explanation on why that happens. “ – yes, I agree. I’m under the impression, that these electricians are good at the hardware side (connecting cables, doing basic checks), but lack knowledge and understanding of the non-visible network parts. I’m not sure, whether this is sufficient part of their education.
Thank you to all here who helped me with their expertise.


The electrical company explained this to me: In rare cases, it can happen that the intermediate switch (in my case, just a network of home routers and repeaters) prevents communication between two devices if they only exchange a few messages with each other. This feature would be called "Data Snooping".

I have literally never heard of this feature, on any switch I've used or read about. I'm having difficulty imagining a use case for it. (It also doesn't make sense as far as implementation goes; every communication, even large transfers, starts with "a few messages" at first – such as the ARP exchange and so on.)
I would say that the electrical company is making things up.
All switches do snoop on every packet so that they could learn which MAC addresses are available through which ports (sort of like the ARP cache but one layer down), and in some cases if you move a device from one switch to another it could be that other switches "further away" will keep directing Ethernet frames in the wrong direction until their MAC cache entry expires and is re-learnt; this can be instant if the device talks first, but it can take a few minutes if the device stays quiet. (Wi-Fi access points send out a dummy broadcast frame on behalf of roaming clients for that reason, and VM live migration often sends an "unsolicited ARP".) It could be that the person you've talked to has seen this happen once and made up their own explanation on why that happens.

To my knowledge, Data Snooping means unauthorized, silent listening to data without manipulation

No, that's not the only use of the term. In network equipment 'snooping' can often be authorized, e.g. the same "IGMP snooping" you mention which causes the switch to learn who's subscribed to which multicast, or "DHCP snooping" which modifies the DHCP requests coming through (typically inserting DHCP Option 82 that identifies the switch port).

Snooping always implies a layering violation. It's peeking at information you're supposed to be oblivious to. A (layer 2) switch shouldn't know anything about IP much less IGMP, so for a switch to parse the frame payload looking for IGMP, that's snooping. It's incorrect to call inspecting your own layer's headers "snooping". 802.1D bridging, including CAM table maintenance, is not snooping.
